# Can I render an id of a tag instead of full page

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Hey guys I am building a website in which the sections of that website are in same html pages and they are given an id ,Now in this special case I want to make a url in django which can go to the specific id not the whole html page

Is this possible?

Comment: Elaborate your question with code/diagrams/whatever.

Comment: Add the `id` after the URL. Example: `<a href="{% url 'some-page' %}#section-id">`